# Hiding dijit.form.DateTextBox

Tags: dojo

I need to keep `dijit.form.DateTextBox` hidden until special event occurs, but next code doesn't work:

> input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="fil1"
>   name="${valueName}_X"  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"

*DateTextBox* is not hidden after page loading and I can't find the way to hide it. I tried adding attribute `style:"visibility:hidden"` - same result.
Are there any other options to hide `dijit.form.DateTextBox`?

Answer (score 1):

**Wrap it inside a div and provide an ID**

```
   <div style="display: none;" id="tabId">
       <input type="hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="fil1" name="${valueName}_X" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" />
   </div>
```

You can then make the div and hence the datetextbox visible by setting display="block".
hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the html generated for the DateTextBox in dojo you will see two layers of elements added to your input element. So you need to control the visibility of top layer which you can achieve by above code (by daur):

To hide:
$("#IdOfElement").parent().parent().hide()
To Show
$("#IdOfElement").parent().parent().show()
This is the best and quick fix

or you may also do:
require
    (
        [ 'dojo/dom-style', 'dijit/registry' ], 
        function (domStyle, registry) 
        {
            domStyle.set(registry.byId("IdOfElement").domNode, 'display', 'none');
        }
    );

change inherit to empty string or inherit if you would like to display again...

Answer (score 1):

The dojo way of doing this is by using dojo/dom-style. So something like:

```
domStyle.set(this.fil1.domNode, "display", "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#IdOfElement").parent().parent().hide()
```

or

```
$("#IdOfElement").parent().parent().show()
```